# Docker-compose having problems with labels

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to setup [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) reverse proxy using example shown in their docs. When I try to bring up 'whoami' service I get following error:

```
Creating test_whoami_1 ... 

ERROR: for test_whoami_1  dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 22; 2 is required

ERROR: for whoami  dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 22; 2 is required
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 121, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 952, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 455, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 70, in parallel_execute
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 22; 2 is required
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Example docker-compose.yml can be found in Traefik docs: 
test/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=whoami"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_webgateway
```

traefik/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:1.4.1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

Using following docker and docker-compose versions:

```
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
docker-compose version 1.17.0, build ac53b73
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: downgrade to docker-compose v1.16.1.

Comment: I can confirm this works in 1.16.1. But why isn't this working in 1.17. Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found an explanation what exactly is causing problems on 1.17.0 - yet.

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose labels is included in version v3.3 and you're running version 1.17.0

Please see the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#label) for more info.

Comment: docker-compose 1.17.0 is the latest release: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/

Also, I tried changing version of docker-compose.yml to version: '3.3' with no success.

Comment: I changed the syntax to this kind of style:
`
labels:
      traefik.backend: "portainer"
`
from 
`
labels:
      - "traefik.backend=portainer"
`
and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I confirm metanerd's answer:

using

```
labels:
  traefik.backend: "whoami"
  traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, with 3.3, you put the tags under the build property
e.g. See below

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  sample-app:
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    build:
      context: .
      labels:
        org.label-schema.build-date: ${BUILD_DATE}
        org.label-schema.commit: ${COMMIT}
...
```

You can see from docker inspect, that the labels have been applied

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .Config.Labels}}' blah/sample-app
```

```
{"org.label-schema.build-date":"2019-05-24-10-36-22","org.label-schema.commit":"2cc11a2"}
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: They can also be at the runtime level (container vs image). Make sure your file "version" is >= '3.3'.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your docker and docker-compose both. It will be fixed automatically.